# Find vertical asymptotes of $\frac{-2 + \sqrt{3x^2-23}}{x-3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So Im trying to see if the following expression has any vertical asymtotes (algebraically without looking at the graph): $$\frac{-2 + \sqrt{3x^2-23}}{x-3}$$

Now after a bit of playing around with factoring stuff out, I figured this would be the equivalent of

$$\frac{-3x-9}{-2-\sqrt{3x^2-23}}$$

But this doesn't really seem all that useful, I managed to cancel the $x-3$ out but I still have a denominator that looks like it might have a vertical asymptote (which it doesn't).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is the original problem ??

Comment: What happens when $x=3$ ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit indeed it seems to be $\frac{0}{0}$, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's a hole does it?

Comment: To get a vertical asymptote we need to divide by zero. In your case the limit at $x=3$ exists & the function is smooth here. So there are no asymptotes (as Heroup says in the answer below) ... Look here for another trick https://www.desmos.com/calculator/exidnvyiym

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look inside the square root.  $3x^2 - 23$ is nonnegative if and only if $|x| \ge \sqrt{23/3}$, which by comparison with $\sqrt{27/3} = 3$, is just a bit smaller in magnitude.  Therefore, the domain of the function $$f(x) = \frac{-2 + \sqrt{3x^2 - 23}}{x - 3}$$ is the set $$\{x : |x| \ge \sqrt{23/3} \cap x \ne 3\}.$$  In this region, of course there is no issue with $x > 3$.  For $x \le -\sqrt{23/3}$, the function is also smooth, but abruptly stops on the boundary point; we cannot call that a vertical asymptote since there is no unbounded behavior there; its value is simply $2/(\sqrt{23/3} + 3)$.  Similarly, there is no asymptote at $x = \sqrt{23/3}$; the function is bounded there.  The only question is whether $$\lim_{x \to 3} f(x)$$ is well defined, and it turns out that the answer is yes:  from your algebra, which is correct, we have $$f(x) = \frac{3(x+3)}{2 + \sqrt{3x^2 - 23}}$$ whenever $x \ne 3$.  So the limiting behavior is $$\lim_{x \to 3} f(x) = \frac{3(3+3)}{2 + \sqrt{3(3^2) - 23}} = \frac{9}{2},$$ meaning that there is also no vertical asymptote at $x = 3$.  The function has no vertical asymptotes anywhere.